# Fiber optic cable connection to switch not working

Tags: fiber, sfp

I am currently working in a project which uses a 12 core SM fiber optic cable running 40 km. Switched are connected in ring topology. Distance between two switches will be max 8 km and i am having 11 switches placed in 40 km. Now between two location its connected to switch via LX/LC SFP. Sensitivity of SFP is-3 dBm to  -19 dBm. While checking the receive power in switch web interface diagnostic page, its showing -11 dBm, that is in acceptable range.

Now the problem is link at switch is not getting up, eventhough power/attenuation is under expected range.

Sometimes in some location, link is getting up at switch, but when i remove it & place it back, its again not working for sometime, but after 10 min it will be up.

I tried replacing the patch cord, cleaning, changing SFP, but having same issue at all location.

Comment: Have you used a proper fiber test rig to test/qualify the fiber?

Comment: You will get nowhere without luck... or a proper measuring equipment. Rent one.

Comment: I found while investigating the case that the fiber used is G.655 standard &  i am using short haul SFP (1310 nm). Whether this can be a issue for link not getting up.

Comment: @ EEAA, i have done OTDR and fiber attenuation is less 3dB loss in the link.